# Eclipse GCC C Cross Compiling for OpenWrt not working

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, openwrt

I am a beginner in both linux and openwrt. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I am following this tutorial : https://downloads.openwrt.org/docs/eclipse.pdf

- Chip : MT7620
- Toolchain Prefix : `mipsel-openwrt-linux-`
- Toolchain Path : `/ligo/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kec+dsp_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.14`

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project hello ****
make all 
Building target: hello
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc -L/ligo/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kec+dsp_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.14/lib -o"hello"  ./main.o   
mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
/ligo/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kec+dsp_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.14/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start_c':
/ligo/openwrt/build_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kec+dsp_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.14/musl-1.1.14/crt/crt1.c:17: undefined reference to `main'
/ligo/openwrt/build_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kec+dsp_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.14/musl-1.1.14/crt/crt1.c:17: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Comment: The error is `undefined reference to 'main'`. You may want to try `int main (void)`, as `main` is type `int`. Your toolchain may be looking for your `void main()` and not finding `void main()` throws the `undefined reference` -- for good reason.

Comment: Try changing the signature of your `main` function to `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` and return zero in the function.

Comment: What is the output of `nm main.o`?

Comment: Thanks everybody, Some how it started when I restarted my OS.

Answer (score 1):

add the following 2 lines at the end of bashrc

- `export PATH=$PATH:~/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kec+dsp_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin
  export STAGING_DIR=~/openwrt/staging_dir`
- `source ~/.bashrc`

To open/create the bashrc you can execute

- `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel stupid when I have to figure this problem which happens too often.

I get the above error when I forget to save the file that contains main() it gives this error since the file is empty until you save it.

These instructions tell how to automatically save all the modified files when you kick off a build [Save before build](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_autosave.htm) Keep this set and you won't see this again.

If you don't have the path to the toolchain set in eclipse, it never even finds a compiler, assembler or linker so it can not produce the error given. The warnings about STAGING_DIR  are harmless in this case.